# How can I get started with PHPUnit, where my class construct requires a preconfigured db connection?

Tags: database, unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit

I have a class that uses a lot of database internally, so I built the constructor with a $db handle that I am supposed to pass to it.

I am just getting started with PHPUnit, and I am not sure how I should go ahead and pass the database handle through setup.

```
// Test code
public function setUp(/*do I pass a database handle through here, using a reference? aka &$db*/){
    $this->_acl = new acl;
}

// Construct from acl class
public function __construct(Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract $db, $config = array()){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do it like this:

```
public class TestMyACL extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    protected $adapter;
    protected $config;
    protected $myACL;

    protected function setUp() {
        $this->adapter  = // however you create a new ZendDbADapter
        $this->config   = // however you create a new config array
        $this->myACL    = new ACL($this->adapter, $this->config); // This is the System  Under Test (SUT)
    }

}
```

IMHO, you need to work on your naming conventions. See [Zend Framework Naming Conventions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html), for a start. An example would be the underscore, look up variables in the link. Also class naming.

Answer (score 1):

You can do normally without reference same as constructor because this method is simplest.

Comment: Do you mean that I should use the same code in my setUp function as I do in my class construct?

Comment: @Ben Dauphinee: Sorry i miss understand your question. You can do normally without reference same as constructor because this method is simplest. You really must use reference for this?